# ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'input_tensor' has invalid shape '[1, None, None, 3]'

Tags: tensorflow, tensorflow-lite, google-coral, edge-tpu

I trained a custom MobileNetV2 SSD model for object detection. I saved the .pb file and now I want to convert it into a .tflite-file in order to use it with Coral edge-tpu.

I use Tensorflow 2.2 on Windows 10 on CPU.

The code I'm using:

```
import tensorflow as tf

saved_model_dir = r"C:/Tensorflow/Backup_Training/my_MobileNetV2_fpnlite_320x320/saved_model"
num_calibration_steps = 100

def representative_dataset_gen():
    for _ in range(num_calibration_steps):
        # Get sample input data as a numpy array
        yield [np.random.uniform(0.0, 1.0, size=(1,416,416, 3)).astype(np.float32)]

converter = tf.lite.TFLiteConverter.from_saved_model(saved_model_dir)
converter.optimizations = [tf.lite.Optimize.DEFAULT]

converter.experimental_new_converter = True

converter.representative_dataset = representative_dataset_gen
converter.target_spec.supported_ops = [
    #tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS_INT8,
    tf.lite.OpsSet.TFLITE_BUILTINS,
    tf.lite.OpsSet.SELECT_TF_OPS
    ]
converter.inference_input_type = tf.int8
converter.inference_output_type = tf.int8

tflite_quant_model = converter.convert()

with open('model.tflite', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(tflite_model)
```

I tried several proposed solutions from other threads and I also tried it with tf-nightly, tf2.3 & tf1.14 but none of it worked (there was always another error message I couldn't handle). Since I trained with tf2.2 I thought it might be a good idea to proceed with tf2.2.

Since I'm new to Tensorflow I have several questions: what exactly is the input tensor and where do I define it? Is there a possibility to see or extract this input tensor?
Does anybody know how to fix this issue?

The whole error message:

```
(tf22) C:\Tensorflow\Backup_Training>python full_int_quant.py
2020-10-22 14:51:20.460948: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'cudart64_101.dll'; dlerror: cudart64_101.dll not found
2020-10-22 14:51:20.466366: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cudart_stub.cc:29] Ignore above cudart dlerror if you do not have a GPU set up on your machine.
2020-10-22 14:51:29.231404: W tensorflow/stream_executor/platform/default/dso_loader.cc:55] Could not load dynamic library 'nvcuda.dll'; dlerror: nvcuda.dll not found
2020-10-22 14:51:29.239003: E tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_driver.cc:313] failed call to cuInit: UNKNOWN ERROR (303)
2020-10-22 14:51:29.250497: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:169] retrieving CUDA diagnostic information for host: ip3536
2020-10-22 14:51:29.258432: I tensorflow/stream_executor/cuda/cuda_diagnostics.cc:176] hostname: ip3536
2020-10-22 14:51:29.269261: I tensorflow/core/platform/cpu_feature_guard.cc:143] Your CPU supports instructions that this TensorFlow binary was not compiled to use: AVX2
2020-10-22 14:51:29.291457: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:168] XLA service 0x2ae2ac3ffc0 initialized for platform Host (this does not guarantee that XLA will be used). Devices:
2020-10-22 14:51:29.298043: I tensorflow/compiler/xla/service/service.cc:176]   StreamExecutor device (0): Host, Default Version
2020-10-22 14:52:03.785341: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:55] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0
2020-10-22 14:52:03.790251: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:356] Starting new session
2020-10-22 14:52:04.559832: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:797] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
2020-10-22 14:52:04.564529: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   function_optimizer: Graph size after: 3672 nodes (3263), 5969 edges (5553), time = 136.265ms.
2020-10-22 14:52:04.570187: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   function_optimizer: function_optimizer did nothing. time = 2.637ms.
2020-10-22 14:52:10.742013: I tensorflow/core/grappler/devices.cc:55] Number of eligible GPUs (core count >= 8, compute capability >= 0.0): 0
2020-10-22 14:52:10.746868: I tensorflow/core/grappler/clusters/single_machine.cc:356] Starting new session
2020-10-22 14:52:12.358897: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:797] Optimization results for grappler item: graph_to_optimize
2020-10-22 14:52:12.363657: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 1714 nodes (-1958), 2661 edges (-3308), time = 900.347ms.
2020-10-22 14:52:12.369137: I tensorflow/core/grappler/optimizers/meta_optimizer.cc:799]   constant_folding: Graph size after: 1714 nodes (0), 2661 edges (0), time = 60.628ms.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "full_int_quant.py", line 40, in <module>
    tflite_model = converter.convert()
  File "C:\Users\schulzyk\Anaconda3\envs\tf22\lib\site-packages\tensorflow\lite\python\lite.py", line 480, in convert
    raise ValueError(
ValueError: None is only supported in the 1st dimension. Tensor 'input_tensor' has invalid shape '[1, None, None, 3]'.
```

Whatever I change in the code, there is always the same error message. I don't know if this is a sign that during training something went wrong but there were no eye-catching occurences.

I'd be happy for any kind of feedback!

Answer (score 0):

Ahh, object detection API with tensorflow 2.0 for coral is still a WIP. We are having many roadblocks and may not see this feature soon. I suggest using tf1.x aPI for now. Here is a good tutorial :)
https://github.com/Namburger/edgetpu-ssdlite-mobiledet-retrain

Comment: Hi Nam, thanks for the fast reply. It's a pity that TF2 is not yet usable for Coral. I already put a lot of effort in it. I also tried to compile the file with edgetpu_compiler in Virtualbox on Ubuntu20.04 and wanted to open another thread for it (because there is another error message). Is there a chance to convert it in this way?

Comment: You see, the problem is that even us are having issues with the 2.x api. 
It's just that there are unimplemented ops that our eng team is still working on. If you want to, you can share your tflite model, I can try a quick run through our latest compiler binary to see if there are improvement?

Comment: Thanks for the offer. Unfortunately, I am not allowed to share the model. 
I guess I have to try it with TF1.x :/ Thanks for the link you mentioned earlier, I try to orientate myself on that...